# Internal Server Error when calling PHP script from ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to call a PHP script using ajax when I click a certain button on the screen. The script will display data in a table that it fetches from an object that contains information fetched from a database in MySQL. I have tested all files separately and they seem to be working perfectly, displaying the tables and the data with no errors. I require one of the files in my main index file which works correctly, but when i try to call any of the files from an anchor/button on the browser it gives an internal server error (500) on the console. I assume there may be an error in the way I am using ajax, or something I may be missing in all this perhaps?

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Dashboard </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="../public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#S").click(function () {
            $.get("../app/views/student/List.php", function (data) {
                $("#Content").html(data);
            })
        });

        $("#C").click(function () {
            $.get("../app/views/course/List.php", function (data) {
                $("#Content").html(data);
            })
        });


        $("#T").click(function () {
            $.get("../app/views/teacher/List.php", function (data) {
                $("#Content").html(data);
            })
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MVC</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="T">Teacher</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="S">Student</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="C">Course</a>
    </ul>
</div>

</nav>


<div id="Content"> <!--this is closed in the footer file-->
```

student/List.php (other list.php are pretty much the same):

```
<?php

require "../core/views/header.php";


use mvcApplication\core\controllers\ControllerFactory;

?>
<button class="col-sm-3" type="submit" onclick="">Add New</button>
<button class="col-sm-3" type="submit" onclick="">Edit Entry</button>
<button class="col-sm-3" type="submit" onclick="">Delete 
Entry</button>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Class</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $init = ControllerFactory::initStudentC();
    $data = $init->show();
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        //echo $d;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php print $d['studentId'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php print $d['name'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php print $d['age'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php print $d['gender'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php print $d['class'] ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

</table>


<?php

require "../core/views/footer.php";
```

Index.php:

```
require_once '../AutoLoader.php';

require '../app/views/student/List.php';
```

Comment: You have error in php code. check for php code

Comment: Run `List.php` seperately

Comment: Look you haven't closed `php` tag in `List.php`. Sometimes it generates problem

Comment: @ZainFarooq I have run each `List.php` separately and they work perfectly. Even when I first run Index.php the data is displayed correctly. It's when I click one of the anchors is when the Internal server error shows up.

Comment: is this `require_once '../AutoLoader.php';` necessary for `List.php`?

Comment: Yes, because the objects being instantiated require `AutoLoader.php` to be in place so that the program knows as to which classes they belong.

Comment: So include it in `List.php` too

Comment: No luck, same error arises.

Comment: Ok.. Do check your path `../app/views/student/List.php`

Comment: checked that as well, invalid path gives a 404 error, meaning the file is being detected when available.

Comment: One last thing... replace `print` with `echo` and do close your php tag

Comment: and remove html code from `List.php`

Comment: `$.get("../app/views/student/List.php", function (data) {
                $("#Content").html(data);
            })` semi-colon `;` is also missing

Comment: It should be like this  `$("#S").click(function () {
            $.get("../app/views/student/List.php", function (data) {
                $("#Content").html(data);
            });
        });`

Comment: nothing's working, I guess there is some problem with the implementation rather than the code itself.

Comment: If you haven't already, try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if anything more helpful shows up in your PHP error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Solved! Thanks to @ZainFarooq 's comment. I needed to put `AutoLoader.php` in `Lists` file as well. The problem was with the paths i forgot to change the paths while requiring it in the `Lists` files.